# Value labels in reputation graph are misplaced

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

If I look at my reputation graph, start with the default "Top 5", and deselect all but the second entry, the labels at the left get messed up:

[image: Repuation graph]

Notice that 250 and 500 are superimposed, and that 750 and 1000 are in the wrong order.

This happens with both Chrome and Firefox.